# issue with ExtentReport logs on pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, extentreports

I have a C# project solution which contains 2 projecsts. One is UI and another one is API. I am using same reusable classes between them for logging. For my UI project, all extent report logs show on pipeline while running but none of my logs when running API test show on pipeline. It shows perfectly fine on ExtentReport. What could be the issue with logging in pipeline ?

my api is an async task Test method.

Expectation is logging that I put should come cause its reflecting when running UI tests.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please try the project solution on local machine, is there any report logs for the API test? If it works on local machine but only no log on pipeline, Please provide more details about your pipeline configuration and how you’re implementing ExtentReports in your tests.

Comment: Can you share pipeline yaml file through which extent reports are logged ?